# Bootstrap 5 Card Header not filling full width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm using tables insides cards (CDN - bootstrap@5.0.2).

The table looks ok in wide widths, but when it is squeezed the card header does not resize to fill the entire width.

This is the HTML.

```
    <div class="card table-responsive">
        <div class="card-header">
            <i class="fas fa-table me-1"></i>
            DataTable Example
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-hover text-center" id="table_summary">
                <!-- I FILL THIS TABLE USING FLASK/JINJA2 -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The full table in the card looking OK

[image: ![enter image description here]

Resized Table looking ok on the left part

[image]

Card Header not filling the entire width when you scroll right.

[image]

Any idea how to make this card header responsive as well?

Comment: Make sure width:100%,, for header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `table-responsive` class from where you have put it and insert it next to class `card-body`

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fas fa-table me-1"></i>
        DataTable Example
    </div>
    <div class="card-body table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover text-center" id="table_summary">
            <!-- I FILL THIS TABLE USING FLASK/JINJA2 -->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can put the `table-responsive` class on it's own `div` element before element `table` as follows

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
    <i class="fas fa-table me-1"></i>
    DataTable Example
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover text-center" id="table_summary">
            <!-- I FILL THIS TABLE USING FLASK/JINJA2 -->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

reference from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#always-responsive

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling the card header has no function. Also, there is no need for nesting the `table` inside a `div.card-body`. You could try:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"><i class="fas fa-table me-1"></i> DataTable Example</div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover text-center" id="table_summary">
            <!-- FILL THIS TABLE USING FLASK/JINJA2 -->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```